# Alfresco community edition-5.1.x how can i start workflow using webscript (java or javascript)?

Tags: javascript, java, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

Alfresco community 5.1.x, i have create custom workflow i need to trigger  via  webscripts (java or javascript) is possible? Please help me with steps because of am new to alfresco?

Comment: What do you mean by 'steps'? In general people will help you better if you can share a little bit about what you have done already, rather than asking for a pre-baked solution, but at a minimum could you comment on whether you are looking for advice on how to implement the web script or how to call it?

Comment: Yes, I have create custom workflow using kickstart in workflow form user going to trigger workflow 2 

1. In workflow form i have one check box if checked check box i need to get some values ex. (activiti id , description ) trigger workflow 2 

How can i do  this ? ,Please help me out

Comment: In that case as you're obviously using the Activiti BPM suite (a.k.a Kickstart) then I'd suggest you use the Activiti REST API to trigger the process. Do a web search, read the docs, try some code out, post it as a new question with some screenshots and people may help you further.

Comment: I am using alfresco community edition ,In community edition how i can use Activiti REST API and Activiti BPM suite

Answer (score 0):

js-api maybe can help you: https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-js-api

```
 //Call a GET on a Web Scripts available at the following URIs:          http://127.0.01:8080/alfresco/service/mytasks

 this.alfrescoJsApi.webScript.executeWebScript('GET', 'mytasks').then(function (data) {
   console.log('Data received form http://127.0.01:8080/alfresco/service/mytasks' + data);    
}, function (error) {
   console.log('Error' + error);
});

//Call a GET on a Web Scripts available at the following URIs: http://127.0.01:8080/share/service/mytasks

this.alfrescoJsApi.webScript.executeWebScript('GET', 'mytasks', null, 'share').then(function (data) {
   console.log('Data received form http://127.0.01:8080/share/service/mytasks' + data);    
}, function (error) {
   console.log('Error' + error);
});

//Call a GET on a Web Scripts available at the following URIs: http://127.0.01:8080/share/differentServiceSlug/mytasks

this.alfrescoJsApi.webScript.executeWebScript('GET', 'mytasks', null, 'share', 'differentServiceSlug').then(function (data) {
   console.log('Data received form http://127.0.01:8080/share/differentServiceSlug/mytasks' + data);    
}, function (error) {
   console.log('Error' + error);
});
```

Comment: I have create javascript file Repository  `/Data Dictionary/Scripts/triggerworkflow.js` how can i call from client javascripts is this possible? please help me out.

Comment: Did you get a look to this two Wiki about how Webscript https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts  https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts_Examples ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call your repo webscript using AJAX like this

```
 var mylink=encodeURI("/webscript-url?parameter1="+value1);

                    Alfresco.util.Ajax.request({

                              url: Alfresco.constants.PROXY_URI + mylink,

                              method: Alfresco.util.Ajax.GET,

                    });
```

Place this code in your repo webscript's JS file and Change the required properties according to your requirement.

```
function startWorkflow()
{
    var value2 = args["parameter1"];// you can get parameter by this
    var workflowAction = workflow.getDefinitionByName("activiti$test_wf");
    var package= workflow.createPackage();

    var wfparams = new Array();
    wfparams["model_prefix:req_props_name"] = value2;

    wfparams["bpm:assignee"] = people.getPerson("admin");
    workflowAction.startWorkflow(package, wfparams);
    }

}

startWorkflow();
```